# Ways to represent a list of numbers?

Tags: statistics

I have a list of random statistical numbers:

> 1, 6, 7, 6, 5, 9, 15, 23, 19, 12

And I want to represents these numbers in a mathematical correct way.  e.g.

> x = { 1, 6, 7, 6, 5, 9, 15, 23, 19, 12 }

But I am not sure if my method is correct.

What different ways are there to represent a list of numbers?

Comment: If the order doesn't matter, you can describe it using a multiset (a set with possible repitition).  If order matters, then you can describe it with a sequence (an ordered multiset).  In either case, you can enclose the entries with braces like you did above.

Comment: The order doesn't matter at all, its only to represent the data so that it can later be used to do calculations with.

Comment: Another option is an [interpolation function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Interpolate[1%2C+6%2C+7%2C+6%2C+5%2C+9%2C+15%2C+23%2C+19%2C+12]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you would just write
$$ \vec x = (1,6,7,6,5,9,15,23,19,12) $$

This can be viewed as a shorthand way of defining the function $f:\{1,2,\ldots,10\}\to\mathbb R$ such that
$$\begin{array}{ccccc} f(1)=1 & f(2)=6 & f(3)=7 & f(4)=6 & f(5)=5 \\
f(6)=9 & f(7)=15 & f(8)=23 & f(9)=19 & f(10)=12 \end{array} $$

Or alternatively, you may prefer to have indexed names for each datum and write
$$ \vec x = (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{10}) = (1,6,7,6,5,9,15,23,19,12) $$

Whether you write $f(3)$ or $x_3$ is mostly a matter of notational convenience.